# I have many-to-many relationship between Orders and Products. What should I do when an order contains product record that was deleted?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have the following 3 tables - `orders`, `products` and `order_products` which have a many-to-many relationship between them.

I have an admin view that displays all orders made, and the products they contain, which is all fine and dandy, however, I realized something undesirable would happen if this scenario occurs:

1. A user orders couple of products
2. The admin deletes a product that was part of the order the user ordered
3. When the admin goes to the view that displays all orders, the user's order would be missing the item that was deleted by the admin in step 2

I guess I want the `order` to keep the `products` that are part of it even if the `product` record from the `products` table is deleted. I think I could do that by adding extra columns to the `order_products` table that would contain the information which is also stored in the `products` records. This means the data will be duplicated, however, the `product` info of the `order` won't be lost if the actual `product` record is deleted.

Comment: I think you should never delete a product that is associated with an order, you need to have a mechanism such as disabled column on product so that it won't be shown when customers are creating the next orders. Another approach is to copy every detail of you product to de order line.

Comment: Why would an admin delete a product?